# Error in if (start > end) stop("'start' cannot be after 'end'") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed in R when try perform minutes forecast

Tags: r, forecasting

I want perform minutes forecast for variable sales

```
timeseries=structure(list(Data = structure(c(10L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 26L, 29L, 
                                             32L, 35L, 38L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 15L, 19L, 23L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 
                                             36L, 39L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 24L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 
                                             40L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 25L), .Label = c("01.01.2018", 
                                                                                              "01.01.2019", "01.01.2020", "01.02.2018", "01.02.2019", "01.02.2020", 
                                                                                              "01.03.2018", "01.03.2019", "01.03.2020", "01.04.2017", "01.04.2018", 
                                                                                              "01.04.2019", "01.04.2020", "01.05.2017", "01.05.2018", "01.05.2019", 
                                                                                              "01.05.2020", "01.06.2017", "01.06.2018", "01.06.2019", "01.06.2020", 
                                                                                              "01.07.2017", "01.07.2018", "01.07.2019", "01.07.2020", "01.08.2017", 
                                                                                              "01.08.2018", "01.08.2019", "01.09.2017", "01.09.2018", "01.09.2019", 
                                                                                              "01.10.2017", "01.10.2018", "01.10.2019", "01.11.2017", "01.11.2018", 
                                                                                              "01.11.2019", "01.12.2017", "01.12.2018", "01.12.2019"), class = "factor"), 
                          client = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L), .Label = c("Horns", "Kornev"), class = "factor"), stuff = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                          3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("chickens", 
                                                                                                                                                                          "hooves", "Oysters"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(374L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             12L, 120L, 242L, 227L, 268L, 280L, 419L, 12L, 172L, 336L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             117L, 108L, 150L, 90L, 117L, 116L, 146L, 120L, 211L, 213L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             67L, 146L, 118L, 152L, 122L, 201L, 497L, 522L, 65L, 268L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             441L, 247L, 348L, 445L, 477L, 62L, 226L, 476L, 306L)), .Names = c("Data", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "client", "stuff", "Sales"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                -40L))
```

Update input data. Now they are write
So i run my script and i get the error

```
 Error in if (start > end) stop("'start' cannot be after 'end'") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 


# Perform forecast
library("lubridate")
# first the grouping variable
timeseries$group <- paste0(timeseries$client,timeseries$stuff)

# determine all groups
groups <- unique(timeseries$group)
# find starting date per group and save them as a list of elements c('YEAR','Month')
timeseries$date <- as.Date(as.character(timeseries$Data), '%dd.%mm.%YY.hh:mm:ss')
timeseries <- timeseries[order(timeseries$date),]
start_dates <- format(timeseries$date[match(groups, timeseries$group)], "%Y %m %d hh:mm")
start_dates <- strsplit(start_dates, ' ')

# Back to your code
# now the list
listed <- split(timeseries,timeseries$group)
str(listed)
# Edited the lapply funcion in order to consider the starting dates
# to have a smaller output, I post the str(listed)

library("forecast")
library("lubridate")
listed_ts <- lapply(seq_along(listed),
                    function(k) ts(listed[[k]][["Sales"]], start = as.integer(start_dates[[k]]))  ) 


listed_ts


listed_arima <- lapply(listed_ts,function(x) auto.arima(x,allowmean = F )) 
#Now the forecast for each arima:
listed_forecast <- lapply(listed_arima,function(x) forecast(x,1440) ) # forecast on 1440 minutes ahead 
listed_forecast

#If you need to flat it down to a data.frame, do.call and rbind help:
do.call(rbind,listed_forecast)


# get fprecast of initial value

lapply(listed_arima, fitted)
```

What  does mean this error?
Most likely I’m doing something wrong, indicating the time format. 
How for each group to get a per-minute forecast for 1440 minutes?

I.E. expected format

```
Data           client   stuff        Sales
10.11.2017 5:15 Horns   chickens    336
10.11.2017 5:16 Horns   chickens    336
10.11.2017 5:17 Horns   chickens    336
10.11.2017 5:18 Horns   chickens    336
```

Comment: Hi d-max, is there an issue in the data you provided? `timeseries$group <- paste0(timeseries$client,timeseries$stuff)` is failing due to missing client and stuff and can not proceed, wondering if there are other gaps. Thanks :)

Comment: @mysteRious, yes, i update my data, but the same error. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max, not sure if the ARIMA results are good here but hopefully this will give you enough info to get unstuck as it shows how to apply a model to groups:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
temp <- rbindlist(listed, fill=TRUE)

temp %>% group_by(group) %>% do(data.frame(v_hat = forecast(auto.arima(.$Sales), h=100))) 
# A tibble: 300 x 6
# Groups:   group [3]
   group         v_hat.Point.Forecast v_hat.Lo.80 v_hat.Hi.80 v_hat.Lo.95 v_hat.Hi.95
   <chr>                        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
 2 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
 3 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
 4 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
 5 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
 6 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
 7 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
 8 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
 9 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
10 Hornschickens                 224.        51.0        397.       -40.5        488.
....
```

Comment: i think here ARIMA(0,0,0) not good:) How to do arima (0,1,0) I accept your answer) can you show arima (0,1,0)

Comment: how insert date for predicted, as in my desired example